# Android findView of Linearlayout and set background in recycleradapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, setbackground

I have a LinearLayout xml with a RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:background="#DBDBDB">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#DBDBDB" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my java class I am setting the background image of whole Linearlayout:

```
LinearLayout linear;
linear = findViewById(R.id.r1);
linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.visitedbg);
```

This is working fine. But I want to set background for the Linearlayout also in Recycleradapter.

In the list the user can remove any item by clicking on it. And if the last item is removed, I want to show a background image.

In `onBindViewHolder`method I have:

```
 movieList.remove(position);notifyDataSetChanged();

if (getItemCount()<=0){holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.visitedbg);}
```

Problem is the Nullpointerexception, as I can't define the LinearLayout view in Recycleradapter.

I tried to put it to  `public MyviewHolder(View itemView)`, also in public `RecyclerAdapter.MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` as

```
 LinearLayout linear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.r1);
```

but this is still not working. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend migrating from findViewById() to viewBindng to prevent app from crashing in running time.
Second, You can only access views inside recyclerView's items from adapter. to implement what you want, you should listen for recyclerView's adapter change. You can use AdapterDataObserver:

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
            //...
        }
    });
```

Take a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver) in android documentation.

Another way to achieve that will be checking for adapter's item count everytime you remove an element:

```
movieList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);

if(adapter.getItemCount() == 0)
    linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.visitedbg)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but in onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) the itemCount is never 0, even if last item is removed, it is still 1. And in my recycleradapter I have  movieList.remove(position);notifyItemRemoved(position);notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Darksymphony implement onChanged() method of same interface instead and check for adapter.getItemCount().

Comment: linear.setBackgroundResource works not, as I can't set linearLayout in recycleradapter. But can you please post an example, where to put onChanged? Instead of onItemRangeRemoved ?

Comment: @Darksymphony as i said in answer, you can't access views outside recyclerview within adapter. you should use this method in the fragment or activity that recyclerview and adapter are declared. you can also use the second way.

Comment: ok, finally it is working. I used recyclerAdapter.getItemCount() inside the registerAdapterDataObserver instead of itemCount  and now it works as expected. Thank you for the advise